# Format Datetime according to the current language

Tags: datetime, localization, cumulocity

I want to format the dates displayed on UI according to the user language, i.e.:

- If selected user language is English: 08/07/2019
- And when he changes to German: 07.08.2019

How is it possible in Cumulocity? Do you have pipes or some functions for datetime localization?

Comment: I think they don't have any configuration for this. btw, are you using Cockpit, a Cockpit based app ?

Comment: No, I use Angular SDK and I guess there is still no cockpit for it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such thing as a locale aware date formatter built into c8y web sdk.

But since it depends on [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) it should not be too complicated to write your own date formatter pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { MomentInput } from 'moment';
import { TranslateService as NgxTranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({ name: 'customdateformatter' })
export class MomentFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private translateService: NgxTranslateService) {}

  transform(value: MomentInput, formatPattern: string): string {
    if (!value) {
      return '';
    }
    return moment(value)
      .locale(this.translateService.currentLang)
      .format(formatPattern);
  }
}
```

If you do not want to specify a custom date format pattern you can always use one of the default ones [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) provides.

```
moment().format('LT');
moment().format('LTS');
moment().format('L');
moment().format('l');
moment().format('LL');
moment().format('ll');
moment().format('LLL');
moment().format('lll');
moment().format('LLLL');
moment().format('llll');
```